# Running 3rd party code on an Azure Function (security concerns)

Tags: azure-functions

I am creating a website similar to dotnetfiddle.net where anyone can submit C# code. I was planning on creating an Azure Function that would compile and run the code. I am wondering if malicious code could somehow mess up my Azure environment? Or is each function execution completely isolated?

Comment: In short, it depends on what your Function is allowed to do, e.g. is it sitting in a vnet that is white-listed in firewall of your prod DB? Does it have authorization to deploy ARM templates? and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Azure Function does not, by default, have permissions to your Azure tenant/subscription. If you have assigned a Managed Service Identity to the App Service running your Function AND granted that identity permissions to your Azure resources, then code executing in your function could have access to your Azure resources.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet

Another consideration is whether you have configured any kind of VNET integration for your function's Web App--if this is the case, code executing in your function would have access to other resources in your VNET.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options